# Problem with bounding box when converting PS to EPS

Tags: eps, ps

I am using GSView version 5 and Ghostscriptversion 9.5 in Windows 10 home edition. When I try to convert Ps->EPS, the resulting EPS figure shows the bounding box neatly around the figure but there is still the remaining A4 size whitespace around the figure. Please help!

Comment: My original figure is drawn using Microsoft Visio Premium 2010, I then printed to file using RICOH PS UniversalDriver V 4.23. I have tried several e.g. HP PS printer etc and I get the same result.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot use PDF? I assume you are including the figure in a Latex document.

Comment: Check if `Options -> EPS Clip` is marked in GSView.

Comment: @Alx, Options -> EPS Clip works in removing the whitespace and leaving the EPS figure with only the tight bounding box thank you!

Comment: @gezuge, my aim is to actually include the figures as pdf in a latex document. I have been using the eps2pdf for windows app (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/eps2pdf/?lang=en) very nicely all along to do my EPS->PDF conversions. For some reason it doesn't convert anymore, whenever I click convert  no output is produced. What could be wrong?